# Issue with framerate limiter (inaccurate)

Tags: c, game-engine

The framerate limiter for this game I'm doing some coding on is having some pretty irritating accuracy issues at certain framerates. I've been scratching my head trying to think of a better way to write this, but the best I've came up with is still fairly inaccurate. I was wondering if someone could give me a couple ideas on how to rewrite this short portion to be more accurate.

```
        //g_dwLastfps & currenttime are equal to timeGetTime()
        float fFrameLimit = 0;
        if (g_nFrameLimitValue > 0) //g_nFrameLimitValue = user defined
            fFrameLimit = 1000 / g_nFrameLimitValue;
        while ((currentTime - g_dwLastTime) < fFrameLimit)
        {
            // -1 = wait an extra ms. seemed to help accuracy some
            Sleep((float)fFrameLimit - ((currentTime - g_dwLastTime)) - 1);
            currentTime = timeGetTime();
        }
        g_dwLastTime = currentTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a pretty simple solution:

```
uint64_t last_time = 0;
uint64_t current_time = time();
uint64_t frame_limit_ms = 17; // 60fps = 16.666... ms/f
uint64_t frame_diff = frame_limit_ms;

sleep(frame_limit_ms);

while(running){
    last_time = current_time;
    current_time = time(); // get frame start time in milliseconds
    frame_diff = current_time - last_time; // get time since last frame in ms

    if(frame_diff < frame_ms_limit){
        sleep(frame_ms_limit - frame_diff);

        // need to do a re-calculation for accuracy
        current_time = time();
        frame_diff = current_time - last_time;
    }

    do_physics(frame_diff);
    draw_scene();
    swap_buffers();
}
```

Which looks a lot like what you have, but doesn't use `float` so should be faster and is accurate up to one unit of time (milliseconds in this case).

If you want it to be more accurate, use a more accurate unit (nanoseconds) and convert it back to milliseconds if you need to.

Comment: But, won't using sleep result in the same framerate issue that I'm running into currently (the user can select anythign up to 1000fps, due ot how the animations react to framerate modifications. some players prefer super high framerates b/c movements appear more smooth, while others prefer a normal framerate)?

Comment: Wait, what exactly is the issue here? Of course 1000fps is going to look smoother than 30fps

Comment: And `sleep` isn't going to be a bottleneck... unless explicitly

Comment: The exact issue is that at certain framerates my limiter seems to begin breaking down, which can cause issues with not only smoothness but the rate of animation cancellations as well. At 120fps my limiter does 125, at 300fps my limiter does 333, at 333-500 my limiter is 500 automatically, and above 500 the limiting fails. I assume this is due to sleep not functioning well above 500ms?

Comment: @Jeff then your platforms `sleep` function has some crazy implementation, because I've written a framerate limiter exactly like my answer before and it's worked perfectly. What `sleep` function are you using? I presume not something from `win32` or `unistd.h`

Comment: Using the default Sleep from synchapi.h (windows of course).

Comment: You shouldn't use that directly, you should just include `windows.h` and define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` if you have to. Also, `Sleep` takes a `uint32_t` argument. Your casting from `float` to `uint32_t` might be causing the strange framerate issues.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with the example code, is that last_time get updated to current_time which gets updated to time(), which can lead to drift over time. To avoid this, last_time should be based on an original reading of time(), and advanced by the desired delay for each frame. The following windows based code is similar what is used in games to keep a thread running at a fixed frequency with no drift. uRem is used to deal with frequencies that aren't exact multiples of the clock frequency. dwLateStep is a debugging aid that gets incremented each instance where the step time is exceeded. The code is Windows XP compatible, where a Sleep(1) can take up to 2 ms, so it checks for >= 2 ms delay pending before using Sleep(1).

```
/* code for a thread to run at fixed frequency */
typedef unsigned long long UI64;        /* unsigned 64 bit int */
#define FREQ    400                     /* frequency */
DWORD    dwLateStep;                    /* late step count */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfFreq;               /* 64 bit frequency */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfTemp;               /* used for query */
UI64 uFreq = FREQ;                      /* process frequency */
UI64 uOrig;                             /* original tick */
UI64 uWait;                             /* tick rate / freq */
UI64 uRem = 0;                          /* tick rate % freq */
UI64 uPrev;                             /* previous tick based on original tick */
UI64 uDelta;                            /* current tick - previous */
UI64 u2ms;                              /* 2ms of ticks */
UI64 i;

    /* ... */ /* wait for some event to start thread */
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liPerfFreq);
    u2ms = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart)+499) / ((UI64)500);

    timeBeginPeriod(1);                 /* set period to 1ms */
    Sleep(128);                         /* wait for it to stabilize */

    QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
    uOrig = uPrev = liPerfTemp.QuadPart;

    for(i = 0; i < (uFreq*30); i++){
        /* update uWait and uRem based on uRem */
        uWait = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) / uFreq;
        uRem  = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) % uFreq;
        /* wait for uWait ticks */
        while(1){
            QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
            uDelta = (UI64)(liPerfTemp.QuadPart - uPrev);
            if(uDelta >= uWait)
                break;
            if((uWait - uDelta) > u2ms)
                Sleep(1);
        }
        if(uDelta >= (uWait*2))
            dwLateStep += 1;
        uPrev += uWait;
        /* fixed frequency code goes here */
        /*  along with some type of break when done */
    }

    timeEndPeriod(1);                   /* restore period */
```